# Three.js hiding objects of loaded model

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have model (exported from Blender) which contains two meshes. One mesh is rigged and animated character, second mesh - hair model. I need to select one of the meshes and hide it or change it's texture. 
I load model like this:

```
jsonLoader.load('./models/character.js', function(geometry, materials) {
    for(var i = 0; i < geometry.animations.length; i++){
        THREE.AnimationHandler.add( geometry.animations[i] );
    }
    var character = new THREE.SkinnedMesh( geometry );
});
```

Now both meshes works like one solid mesh.

Answer (score 2):

You can make an object invisible by setting its `visible` property to `false`.

```
character.visible = false;
```

Comment: You misunderstood my issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert this two meshes in two different objects to make them selectable (see this [nice post](http://soledadpenades.com/articles/three-js-tutorials/object-picking/) to learn how to select an object).

Once the object is selected you can change its property to make it visible or hide it.